# Open a file in a specific instance of Kile

Tags: kile

This question is potentially off-topic, but hear me out. It's not actually to do with LaTeX, but rather with one of its editors -- Kile. There's a `[kile]` tag, so I think I'm justified in asking this here.

I have two instances of Kile open via the command line, by typing

```
~$ kile &
~$ kile --new &
```

This gives me two windows with Kile. I'm trying to edit one set of files in one and another set in the other window.

Typing `kile <file> &` in the command line always opens files in the first window opened. How do I specify which instance to open the file in? Or is my understanding of the whole process incorrect?

Th emotivation for this is that the GUI for opening files is behaving slowly, due to some network issues (above my paygrade to understand) but the workaround I have is accessing files via the command line (which is as fast as usual, for some reason).

N.B.: Using the command line interface in Kile or the terminal provided by the OS does not change the behaviour.

Comment: This is probably more a window manager issue than Kile per se. KDE used to be very sophisticated about these possibilities, but the new version gutted the lot and it is now generally hopeless on this kind of thing. (But you may not be using KDE, of course.)

Comment: I think my institution uses Kubuntu (I'm not sure if that's the same thing as KDE, though).

Comment: I think - but I'm not positive - that it probably uses KDE. That is, it is probably Ubuntu with the desktop environment switched for KDE.